# c#でのADO.NET を用いたExcelファイル読み込み方法について

Tags: c#

c# でexcelファイル（xls）を読み込んだ値を別のテキストファイルに出力する処理をwindowsサーバー上で検討中です。
なお、この処理はタスク起動によるバックグラウンド処理となります。

前回の質問：[c#でのExcelファイル読み込み方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/50337/c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%aeexcel%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e8%aa%ad%e3%81%bf%e8%be%bc%e3%81%bf%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)

オープンソースの使用は避けたい中、ADO.NET (ODBC）を使用した方法は、
どうかと考えております。

windows server 2012 R2にデフォルトでインストールされているODBC Excelドライバー　32bit でExcelファイル（xls、xlsx）の読み込みは可能でしょうか？
可能であればExcelのインストールをしないでc#の標準の機能だけで対応可能と考えております。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excelは表計算ソフトであり、厳密にはデータベースではありません。データベース的なアクセス方法で問題ないのでしょうか？

Windowsには

- [ODBC Jet SQLConfigDataSource (Excel Driver)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-jet-sqlconfigdatasource-excel-driver?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Jet Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-microsoft-jet?view=sql-server-2017)

などがインストールされていますが、これらは互換のために残されているコンポーネントで32bit版しか提供されていません。ODBCよりはOLE DBの方が使われている気がします。
これらとは別に

- [ACE; Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

が用意されています。こちらは個別にインストールする必要がありますが、ExcelやAccess本体は不要です。また64bit版も提供されています。ただし、残念なことに公式ドキュメントはなさそうです。

Comment: おそらく「公式ドキュメント」は前回回答記事に追記したSQL Server Integration Servicesの解説ページでしょう。それで十分かは不明ですが。

Comment: ありがとうございます。リンクの記事を拝見したところ、ASEは、サーバーバッチ処理はNGのようです。

Comment: Excelファイルは、表形式ではない（各行で列の数はバラバラ）ですが、指定シートの内容をすべて読み込むことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: @mame 前質問で指摘したサーバー上での使用がサポートされない件はOfficeアプリケーション（実行ファイル）の設計に起因する問題です。対して、ACEの問題はOfficeファイル形式が複数ユーザーなどによる同時アクセスを想定していない問題であり、アクセス方法に依らず常に危険であり、もちろんODBCであっても同じです。これに関してはファイル形式を改める以外に手段がなく、そうであれば、本質問が成立しません。

Comment: @sayuri 対象のExcelファイルは、処理前に一時フォルダに格納し複数ユーザの同時アクセスはしません。そうであればODBCやACEの問題は、無いと考えてよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

多分出来るんじゃないでしょうか。こんな記事があります。
概要はGoogle翻訳で訳せばわかるでしょう。
[Getting Data between Excel and SQL Server using ODBC](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/getting-data-between-excel-and-sql-server-using-odbc/)

ただ、こちらにあるように動いているExcelの64bit/32bitの別で影響があるかもしれません。
[ODBCのText DriverとExcelとを使ってCSVファイルをSQLで検索・抽出する](http://haneimo.hatenablog.com/entry/20160830/1472527773)

> 注意しなければならないのは、、、 
>   Excelが32bit版ならOS付属の32bit版のTextDriverを使う。
>   Excelが64bit版ならAccessに付属している64bit版のText Driverを使う。

それからWindows Updateの適用状況によっては、不具合が出る場合があるようです。
[【KB4041681】外部データベース ドライバー(1)で予期しないエラーが発生しました。](https://qiita.com/yaju/items/2d05527ff64643c99fcf)